# Why does SSL Labs say that POODLE is mitigated if a server chooses RC4?

Tags: tls, known-vulnerabilities

I always thought that if a server supports SSLv3 and CBC ciphers, then it is vulnerable to POODLE. But it looks like that is not the case.

For example, [for Google.com, SSL Labs says that the SSL POODLE attack is mitigated](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=216.58.192.14) even though it supports CBC ciphers with SSLv3. On further investigation, I found that if SSL Labs detects that a server prefers RC4 over CBC (SSL 3: 0x5 is mentioned next to SSL POODLE result).

Now MITM can only provide CBC ciphers to Google.com, then it will only choose CBC (out of what I provide), and it will still be vulnerable to POODLE. But then why does SSL Labs says it is not?

Answer (score 2):

[Ivan Ristic explains this in a blog post](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/10/15/ssl-3-is-dead-killed-by-the-poodle-attack):

> In the short term, it’s possible to mitigate POODLE by avoiding using CBC suites with SSL 3, but that involves relying on a certain insecure stream cipher whose name no one wants to mention. I don’t recommend this approach.

And that *insecure stream cipher* (suite) is this:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)
```

Comment: But that is because ssllabs would have sent client handshake request with stream ciphers in it. My question is - it is possible for a MITM to send only CBC ciphers in that case chosen cipher would be a CBC which makes it poodle vulneable (?).

Comment: If you support CBC ciphers in SSLv3, you're vulnerable to POODLE. Simple as that. The mitigation Google have is the `TLS_SCSV_FALLBACK` function which makes it impossible for an attacker to downgrade you to SSLv3 if you support TLSv1.0 and your client is SCSV aware.

Answer (score 2):

Risk scoring is not always clear-cut. Here are some of the considerations SSL Labs has to deal with when [scoring a situation](https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_Server_Rating_Guide.pdf) like this:

- Some servers have an operational need to support a wide variety of old or unpatched clients. Prioritizing stream ciphers over CBC ciphers can partially mitigate POODLE from a *server's* perspective, leaving it up to the client to support the best it can.
- RC4 is bad, and already caps the score at B (for pre-TLS 1.1 protocols).
- SSLv3 is bad, and already caps the score at B (fails entirely if nothing but SSLv3 is supported).
- POODLE is not a high-risk vulnerability for most, since it requires a man-in-the-middle attack and there are many configurations that are not vulnerable.
- Google probably supports TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV to protect TLS-supporting clients from being forcibly downgraded to the POODLE-prone SSLv3 setup. This is an additional mitigation that ensures only the most out-of-date (i.e. SSLv3-only) clients could be exploited.

Given these inputs, SSL Labs has decided that prioritizing RC4 and supporting TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV is a sufficient server-side mitigation for POODLE, which will also have the effect of reducing the overall score.